# in Scala, how to avoid overriding super.method() in a subclass?

Tags: scala, inheritance, superclass, super

I have 3 classes:

```
class B extends A {
  def sup: Unit = {
    super.method()
  }

  override def method(): Unit = {
  ....
  }
}

object C extends B
```

If I call C.sup(), instead of calling method() of A, it will call the overriden method() of B, is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the behavior your describe:

```
C:\...>scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class A {
  def method(): Unit = println("A.method")
}

class B extends A {
  def sup(): Unit = super.method()
  override def method(): Unit = println("B.method")
}

class C extends B

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class A
defined class B
defined class C

scala> val c = new C
c: C = C@62833051

scala> c.sup()
A.method
```

As you can see, `c.sup()` calls `A.method`, not `B.method`.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, turns out that the problem is caused by thread safety.